# Is using useEffect absolutely necessary?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I've been using React Hooks for a few months and have strictly adhered to using the `useEffect` hook as per the documentation.

A new colleague has joined the team and he is asking why is `useEffect` necessary.  We've gone through the documentation together but he points out that implementing `useEffect` causes extra renders.

Here is a simple use case: A button is pressed to fetch some data.  The click is handled by a Click event handler.  He is wondering why he can't make the async call to the endpoint directly within the event handler.

I'm looking for an explanation that goes beyond "the docs say you shouldn't" and actually explains what the danger or downside of doing this is.

Might anyone be able to share why?

Comment: he can. `useEffect` is used to perform side effect when component is mounted or updated. Similar to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: @sam Yes, using `useEffect` to replace those lifecycle events are definite use cases but it has uses far beyond those.

Answer (score 1):

In short it's used for any side effects (not only fetching data):

A side effect is any application state change that is observable outside the called function other than its return value. Side effects include:

- Modifying any external variable or object property (e.g., a global
  variable, or a variable in the parent function scope chain)
- Logging to the console
- Writing to the screen
- Writing to a file
- Writing to the network
- Triggering any external process
- Calling any other functions with side-effects

Side effects are mostly avoided in functional programming, which makes the effects of a program much easier to understand, and much easier to test.
Haskell and other functional languages frequently isolate and encapsulate side effects from pure functions using [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)).

Comment: Thanks for this.  What you've outlined is also my understanding about React Hooks and Functional programming.  I'd be curious about your thoughts of what Matt Aft wrote below.